# Neo4j representation of graph - internals

Tags: neo4j

I have a question regarding how a graph in Neo4j is loaded into memory
from disk.

Reading the link [here](http://www.slideshare.net/thobe/an-overview-of-neo4j-internals), I think I understand how the graph is represented on
disk. And when a new Neo4j databases is created, there are 
physically separate files created for Nodes, Edges and Property
stores (mainly).

When you issue a query to Neo4j, does it:

1) Load the entire graph(nodes, edges, properties) in memory using a
doubly link list structure?

OR

2) Determine the nodes, edges required for the query and populate the
list structure with random accessess to the relavant stores(nodes,
edges) on disk? If so, how does Neo4j minimize the number of disk-accesses?

Comment: More like #2, but that isn't exactly it.  You should try running `PROFILE` on some cypher queries, and examining the plan that it generates.  This will give you concrete examples of how it accesses information.

Answer (score 2):

As frobberOfBits mentions it's more like #2. The disc accesses are minimized by a two-layered cache architecture which is best described in the [reference manual](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/configuration-caches.html).
Even if your cache is smaller than the store files this results mostly in seek operations (since a fixed record length) with a read. This kind of operations are typically fast (even faster with appropriate hardware like SSD)